# Store and retrieve a file from server with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I made a Word application which does create contracts with serial numbers (p.s. Kontrata_101), I do this with `AutoNew` macro (from [here](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/NumberDocs.htm)):

```vb
Sub AutoNew()

    Order = System.PrivateProfileString("C:\Settings.Txt", "MacroSettings", "Order")
    If Order = "" Then
        Order = 1
    Else
        Order = Order + 1
    End If
    System.PrivateProfileString("C:\Settings.txt", "MacroSettings", "Order") = Order
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Order").Range.InsertBefore Format(Order, "00#")
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="path" & Format(Order, "00#")

End Sub
```

Is there any way to save and increase numbers from a server, from where we can have access more than one pc, and to increase numbers every time word opens in any of our pc.

Comment: I guess all of your PCs are connected in one network? Do you have any servers or at least any shared network drives in the network?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention, we are connected in one network and we have servers (I work on ISP company, so servers are not an issue).

Comment: You may store the number in simple text file or Access DB file on shared drive, VBA code will open it in exclusive mode, read the number and increase it. Or more robust way is to create e. g. HTTP server with simple php script returning the number and increasing it in DB.